# Error: Could not find a valid gem 'wxruby' (>=0) in any repository

Tags: installation, rubygems

```
C:\Users\me>gem install wxruby
ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'wxruby' (>=0) in any repository
ERROR: Possible Alternatives: tx-ruby, rx_ruby, swxruby, fxruby, dxruby
```

"gem install wxruby-ruby19" gives the same result, too.

having https://rubygems.org/ in sources.
having installed other stuff via "gem install", and since it's giving me some possible alternatives, I guess I'm having no problem connecting to rubygems.org.

Any idea?

Comment: have you tried installing via Gemfile?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: see [Bundler](http://bundler.io/), It will allow you to install and manage gems using gemfile

Comment: it says "Could not find gem 'wxruby (=2.0.1) x64-mingw32' in rubygems repository https://rubygems.org/. Source contains 'wxruby' at: ... 2.0.1 x86-mingw32 ..." How can I install that 2.0.1 x86-mingw32 instead?